# Is The Flow Chart of the program correct?

Tags: flowchart

Calculate one child’s allowance, based upon 75 cents per year old if s/he is under 10, and $1 per year if 10 or over.
I could have stated them at the beginning as well but is the use of the rate variables after the decision box correct?

[image: Flowchart]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's functionally correct.

You could get rid of some of the sections if you wish by just using one variable to store the rate (rather than rate1 / rate2), and then just using the decision block to set the variable differently. You then wouldn't need to duplicate the last two statements.

Comment: Thanks for the help.